# How can I compress DICOM images?

Tags: image-processing, image, compression

I have 193 dcm files in a folder. I will like to combine these images into .dcm.gz format (e.g. images.dcm.gz) and I was wondering how this could be done in Mathematica. Thank you in anticipation of your kind suggestions!

My directory:
[image]

Comment: "I will like to combine these images in a gzip" <-- A gzip file cannot hold more than one file. It always holds only a single one. This is why tar is typically used together with gzip: tar is for combining, gzip is for compressing. Each tool has a single function according to the Unix philosophy.

Comment: Oh! thank you for the clarification. All I just want to do is to combine the dcm files into a single file in .dcm.gz format. Meanwhile, I have made appropriate edits to my question.

Answer (score 4):

## `Export` "ZIP"

As explained by @Szabolcs, [`"GZIP"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/GZIP.html) will not accept more than one file, so here I show an example with [`"ZIP"`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/ZIP.html).

Where I use a single image, you can have many.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZ8oj.png"]
```

[image]

```
Export[
    "TestFile.ZIP"
    ,{
        img
    }
    ,{
        "ZIP"
        ,{
            {"image.dcm","DICOM"}
        }
    }
]
```

[image]

In your case, change the list `{img}` with all the image objects and `{{"image.dcm","DICOM"}}` with the file and format names.

## `CreateFile`

Alternatively you could use [`CreateFile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateFile.html) with a similar syntax.

Comment: @ rhermans, I dont understand what you meant by "change the list {img} with all the image objects", I have made some modifications to the question in this direction. Many thanks!